# toggle button seen on desktop view

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">Home</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

with the code above i can still see the toggle button while i view the page in desktop
[image: toggle]

Comment: question is a bit unclear

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i3sawk
please take a look in screenshot upload in the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong class name in your toggle button. Use `navbar-toggler` instead of `navbar-toggle`

> [*Reference Link* ***bootstrap4 navbar***](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: instead of navbar-toggle class use **navbar-toggler** for button class